# Accessing Word documents in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-word

I have a number of documents (mainly Word and Excel) that I'd like to make available to users of my Rails app. However, I've never tried something like this before and was wondering what the best way to do this was? Seeing as there will only be a small number of Word documents, and all will be uploaded by me, do I just store them somewhere in my Rails app (i.e. public/docs or similar) or should I set up a separate FTP and link to that? Perhaps there's an even better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're to be publically accessable, you definitely just want to stick them in `public` somewhere.  Write a little helper to generate the URL for you based on however you want to refer to them in your app, for cleanliness (and so if you do change the URL later, for example to [bucket your files to keep your directory sizes under control](http://www.anchor.com.au/hosting/dedicated/efficient_file_storage#head-0223cc36898f2a8676ccf5fdf47f6df9ebee95db), you don't have to change links all over your app, just in one place.

If, on the other hand, your files are only for logged-in users, you'll need to use something like [`send_file`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html#M000266) to do the job, or one of the webserver-specific methods like the `X-Sendfile` header to check the user is authorised to view the file before sending it back to them.

Comment: The users that will access the documents will be logged in so this is just what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed in using send_file or X-Sendfile (and friends), but in this case make sure you don't place your files under the public directory.

Answer (score 2):

I would do as you suggested and put them in public/docs. If you are planning on making an overview/index page for the files and link directly to them it would be easier if they were stored locally instead of a remote FTP server. However, since you are the one who will be uploading and maintaining these files, I think you should go with the option that's easiest for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Georg. Womble's answer was slightly more useful so I've marked that one. No hard feelings.